# Django - Save checked checkboxes on reload

Tags: html, django

I am trying to save checked off checkboxes.

The issue I am having right now is that when I press the email button, the page goes blank and when I try to go back, it asks me if I want to "Confirm Form Resubmission". I also tried linking the same page back like this in the form tag:

```
<form action="{% url 'ordered_user_list' %} method="post">
```

Note that the email button shouldn't do anything except reload the same page, but have the boxes checked as before. Also, if I come back to it from a different page, it should still be checked off as before.

in html file

```
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><u><a href="{% url "ordered_user_list" %}">Last Name</a></u></th>
        <th><u><a href="{% url "ordered_user_list_first" %}">First Name</a></u></th>
        <th style="width: 30%"><u><a href="{% url "ordered_user_list_email" %}">Email</a></u></th>
        <th><u>Phone</u></th>
      </tr>
    {% for user in object_list %}
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="emailList" value="{{user.id}}"></td>   
        <td><a href="{% url "user_info" user.id %}"> {{ user.lastName|capfirst }}</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url "user_info" user.id %}">{{ user.firstName|capfirst }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class = "btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Email"/></form>
```

in View file

```
class OrderedUserList(ListView):
   model = User

   template_name = "Schedule/ordered_user_list.html"


   def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated() or (not self.request.user.admin and not self.request.user.volunteer_coordinator):
        return forbidden()
    checked = request.POST.get('emailList')
    return super(OrderedUserList, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the selections by setting a COOKIE(in your view) by using the 'set_cookie' command.You can then access this cookie within your session and get the values of selections wherever you want.But remember that 1)the cookie saves your selection as a single string so be careful about how you save your selections so it is easier to extract them later (using string split method) and 2)it has a downside that this will be a system-dependent solution as the cookie wont be accessible if you save a cookie on one device and try to login from some other device/system at the same time.Hope this helps....